# nodemailer doesn't send mails when run on server

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Hy, I have a little problem with nodemailer. When I run script on my computer I get email, but when I run script on server I get NO EMAIL.
I am working also with MongoDb. So inside "co" function I go look in database ("search for some informations") and than when I get information, I send email.

```
co(function *(){
  //searching for information. I find them and save them to array urls. 
  console.log(urls);

    var fileName=[];   
    for(var i=0;i<urls.length;i++)
    {   
    //I must do this because of buffer ("fs.readFile("./final_pdf/"+fileName")
    //why?? I don't know. Buffer must receive array
    var file=urls[i][0];        
    fileName=file;

    fs.readFile("./final_pdf/"+fileName, function (err, data) {
        var mailOptions= 
        {
            from: 'something@something.net', 
            to: emailDevice, 
            subject: 'Something', 
            text: 'Hello',
            attachments: 
            [{
                filename: fileName,
                contentType: 'application/pdf',
                contents: new Buffer(data, 'base64')
            }]              
        };
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error){
            if(error){
                return console.log(error);
            }
            console.log('PDF sent');
        });
    });
    }
```

});

So I do not know where is the point. When I run on my computer works fine, I get emails. Then I run on server and get 4x message "PDF sent" BUT NO EMAILS, nothing. Also not in spam.

Comment: Also I forget to tell, that I can send email outside the "co" function, BUT I need this because of the "informations from database". Is any possibility to get this "data" outside of "co" function??

Comment: You're going to want to call the `yield` keyword on transporter.sendMail() here. As the nodemailer module has a callback based API, you will need to use a co wrapper around nodemailer. I would recommend  comailer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/comailer

Comment: What transporter you are using?